# Rails session cookie not getting set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, cookies

I have a rails app that is a CMS that uses dynamic subdomains for each site.  For some reason when I deployed to production the session cookie is not getting set.  I'm thinking this is leading to the "Invalid Authenticity Token" errors that are being thrown everywhere.

I have my production.rb setup so that I can share sessions across subdomains.  What could be going wrong that the cookie isn't being set at all?

```
#production.rb
config.action_controller.session[:domain] = '.domain.com'


#environment.rb
config.action_controller.session = {
   :session_key => '_app_session',
   :secret      => '.... nums and chars .....'
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following in your production.rb:

`config.action_controller.session = {:domain => '.domain.com'}`

Comment: Can't, doing that overwrites the config.action_controller.session variable with a new hash, which is already initialized in environment.rb.  This leads to an error wanting a :session_key, and :secret.